# What is the name and value of this component?

Tags: diodes, components

This is the image of the charging circuit using a BQ24133RGYT.

- I need help regarding the diode D3 connected to the STAT pin. What type of diode is it?
- What is the name of the component connected to the TS pin with value 103AT?
- If anyone has gone through the BQ24133RGYT datasheet, what factors should I keep in mind for selection of diodes D1, D2 and D3 in this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to EE. You reference an image, however image is not shown. About the datasheet and footprints - if you do some research in the matter, you can ask a new question about your own choice / thoughts about those footprints. It goes to show that you do some effort on your behalf. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding the picture.

Comment: D3 is an LED, this will light up when the STAT pin goes low. Rt is a thermal resistor, that changes its resistance relative to the temperature. It used to prevent overheating of the battery. D3 isn't anything special, just make sure the current doesn't exceed the pin current. I haven't read the datasheet, but D1 and D2 seem to be schottkey diodes. They have a low forward voltage drop.

Comment: Is a BOM available in the application note?

Comment: @BasVisscher The arrows point in the wrong direction.

Comment: @winny, What do you mean? What arrow is in the wrong direction?

Comment: @BasVisscher:  An LED symbol has arrows pointing away from the diode to symbolize the light leaving the diode.  The symbol in the given schematic shows the arrows pointing at the diode.  That is the symbol for a photodiode - it reacts to light rather than producing light.

Comment: @JRE, Ah I didn't notice that. It seems to be a fault in the datasheet. The datasheet specifies the following for the STAT pin: "Open-drain charge status pin with 10-kΩ pullup to power rail. The STAT pin can be used to drive LED or communicate with the host processor. It indicates various charger operations: LOW when charge in progress. HIGH when charge is complete or in SLEEP mode. Blinking at 0.5 Hz when fault occurs,
including charge suspend, input overvoltage, timer fault and battery absent."

Comment: @BasVisscher Seems they picked the wrong symbol

Answer (score 4):

Diode D3 is an LED.  The example schematic shows a photodiode, but that is an error in the drawing.  For an LED, the arrows point away from the diode.

The LED is simply a status indicator, showing what the charging circuit is doing.  It is connected to the "STAT" pin.

Description of the "STAT" pin from the pin descriptions on page 6 of the [BQ24133RGYT datasheet:](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24133.pdf)

> Open-drain charge status pin with 10-kΩ pullup to power rail. The STAT pin can be used to drive LED or communicate with the host processor. It indicates various charger operations: LOW when charge in progress. HIGH when charge is complete or in SLEEP mode. Blinking at 0.5 Hz when fault occurs,
> including charge suspend, input overvoltage, timer fault and battery absent.

The example circuit from the datasheet shows D3 being powered from the \$V_{REF}\$ pin of the IC.  That's 3.3V.  With R10 = 1.5k, you'll only get a couple of milliamperes through D3.  Practically any indicator LED will work.  You can get up to 35mA out of the \$V_{REF}\$ pin of the IC - you could lower R10 a lot.  I wouldn't do that, though. Modern LEDs are incredibly bright at low current.  An indicator LED powered with the maximum allowed current (typically 20mA) is eye searingly bright.

The part marked "103AT" connected to pin "TS" is a thermistor used to monitor the temperature of the battery.  [It is a thermistor rated for 10 kohm at 25 C.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/362/semitec_atthermistor-1202913.pdf)

Description of the "TS" pin from the pin descriptions on page 6 of the [BQ24133RGYT datasheet:](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24133.pdf)

> Temperature qualification voltage input. Connect a negative temperature coefficient thermistor. Program the hot and cold temperature window with a resistor divider from VREF to TS to AGND. The temperature qualification window can be set to 5-40°C or wider. The 103AT thermistor is recommended.

The diodes D1 and D2 are simply reverse polarity protection for the IC (pin AVCC) to prevent damage from an incorrectly connected battery or external supply.  They are Schottky diodes to minimize voltage drop. The value shouldn't be critical in any way, really.

Comment: Thank u I , still have one doubt what will be the forward voltage and forward current for the LED to be selected

Comment: @Rafae:  I've added some information to my answer.  Please read through the datasheet carefully.  You are working with lithium batteries - they do not take kindly to mistreatment.  They are very intolerant of mistakes.  Make sure your circuit is correct before you connect a real battery to the charger.

Comment: Thank u again I read the datasheet and went through everything and made the whole circuit with proper Footprints and components, only 1 thing is remaining that is selection of Diodes ( D1 and D2) . In datasheets found out these are TVS zener diodes but I ain't getting what should be the current through them and what other values should I keep in mind while selecting these diodes

Comment: D1 and D2 are Schottky diodes.  They are simply there to prevent reverse polarity from killing the IC. Pretty much any Schottky diode rated for at least 500mA should do.  The IC itself shouldn't draw more than maybe 100mA.

Answer (score -1):

- I need help regarding the diode D3 connected to the STAT pin. What
  type of diode is it?

This is basic knowledge, you should read about the different types of diodes and you will find out about this one.

Edit: See JREs comment below.

- What is the name of the component connected to the TS pin with value 103AT?

It's a thermistor, NTC type.

- If anyone has gone through the BQ24133RGYT datasheet, what factors should I keep in mind for selection of diodes D1, D2 and D3
  in this circuit?

*About the datasheet and footprints - if you do some research in the matter, you can ask a new question about your own choice / thoughts about those footprints. It goes to show that you do some effort on your behalf.*

Comment: D3 is basic knowledge, except that the one shown in the schematic has the wrong symbol.  There should be an LED there, but the schematic shows a photodiode.  If you read the pin descriptions on page 6 of the datasheet, you will see that an LED is to be connected to the STAT pin.

Comment: Oh dear, I took a glimpse and registered it in my mind as a LED, but sure the symbol isn't.